# Are bureaucracy and civil service synonyms?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

If so, should tags [bureaucracy](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bureaucracy) and [civil-service](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civil-service) be merged?

Answer (score 5):

No, and so no they shouldn't. There's bureaucratic processes outside of the civil service; particularly in legislatures.

Comment: Or inside political parties themselves (there were some questions here about that, although not all clearly taggeged), i.e. bureaucracy exists in private orgs as well.

Comment: … and any form of business. Now often required, expanding & enforced by government and legislature *for private businesses.* Whether financial, documentation, 'Quality management' and so on… So yeah: No & no.